# simple wp_insert_post example

Tags: customization, posts, functions

i've spent way too much time trying to use the `wp_insert_post()` function a `<form>` and i do not know why it is not working.

```
// Create post object
  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'My post',
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_author' => 1,
     'post_category' => array(8,39)
  );

// Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

I'm probably doing something wrong.

If possible can you please hook this to a form. Thanks verymuch.
I just need an example to see what i am doing wrong.

here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321914/wp-insert-post-with-a-form) to where i previously asked. pls don't mark dupe.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_title']    = 'My post';
$my_post['post_content']  = 'This is my post.';
$my_post['post_status']   = 'publish';
$my_post['post_author']   = 1;
$my_post['post_category'] = array(0);
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );"
```

This works fine. You code is correct, but it is an problem in the form to send the $_POST data?
See on [this post](http://wpengineer.com/1229/puplishing-extend-of-wordpress/) for feature informations